# Check for idle condition in running python program - Euler #41

Tags: python, optimization, permutation

I want to find a solution to `Spoiler alert Euler #41 problem`. The question I have asked is sub-problem of it. I have the solution to the questions but the problem is in the solution. Here is the actual thing I am checking for : -

```
large = 0
x = ''

for i in range(1,10):
x += '%d' %i
for perm in permutations(x):
    if(isPrime(int(perm))):
        large = perm

print large
```

and here is the permutations function:-

```
def permutations(val):
    res = []
    if len(val) == 1:
        res = [val]
    else:
        for i, c in enumerate(val):
            for perm in permutations(val[:i]+val[i+1:]):
                res += [c+perm]

return res
```

The above program finds the permutations for all prime numbers in the permutations from 1 to 987654321.

But the problem is after large = 7652413, there is no further growth in large. The program hits this value in about 3 seconds, but the program completes in about 4 minutes. So I was wondering if there was any way to shave off time on this.

This question can also be generalized as a way to find if a function which tells you if the function is taking too long to get the desired result.

Comment: This is related to [the halting problem](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). In the general case you can't do it, but in this case you may be able to tell by analysis that certain length numbers (or some other criteria) can't be solutions.

Comment: Ya, I meant in this case, just give a kind of feedback function which tells you that.

Comment: @Strommer: What kind of "feedback function"? If you have a heuristic in mind (something simple like `large` doesn't increase for N iterations or M seconds, or something smart based on mathematical knowledge), you have to describe it or nobody can tell you how to code it.

Comment: @abarnert I am not really sure, this is the first time I have come accross such a problem, as in one in which I need to find out if it stops before completion. It didn't strike me that it is a halting problem till  mentioned earlier.

Comment: This is really two separate problems: "any way to shave off time on this" and "a way to find… if the function is taking too long". So, I think it would have been better asked as two questions. (You can always put links between them to make it obvious how they're related.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a way to apply a timeout as a heuristic to tell you that you're "probably done", and stop working.

The easy way to do that is to get the current time at the start or each time you increment `large` (depending on which one you think is relevant), then check the time since then every so often and cancel if you go past it.

If it's not reasonable to manually "check every so often" in your code, you can use a background thread to do it, but let's keep things simple, because that doesn't seem to be necessary here.

So:

```
class Timeout(object):
    def __init__(self, timeout_seconds):
        self.timeout = datetime.timedelta(0, timeout_seconds)
        self.reset()
    def reset(self):
        self.start = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.stop = self.start + self.timeout
    def check(self):
        if datetime.datetime.now() > self.stop:
            raise Exception('Timeout!')
```

Now, you can do this:

```
t = Timeout(30)
for perm in permutations(x):
    if isPrime(int(perm)):
        large = perm
        t.reset()
    t.check()
```

---

If you want to use the number of loops since update instead of the number of seconds, or some fancier heuristic, it's no any more complicated. You just need to describe the heuristic, then translate it into code.

Comment: This does help and I think it would just be possible for a probable answer right? nothing conclusive

Comment: @Strommer: Well, yes, but how "probable" is difficult to guess without a lot of thought. In this case, once you put that much thought into it, you'll hopefully come up with Bhajun Singh's answer and it won't even be an issue… but more generally, probabilistic algorithms are interesting, useful, and very tricky. Let's say after timeout you start randomly checking only some permutations, and gradually decrease the frequency, instead of just stopping. What are the odds that you get the right answer? It might be fun to simulate it with smaller cases and draw a curve…

Answer (score 2):

Answering only the direct question at hand, you can speed up your code significantly by using `itertools.permutations`.

But, mathematically, you can reduce your problem by realizing that your desired prime can have at most 7 digits.  If it had 8, then `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = 36`, which is divisible by 3 and so cannot be prime.  Adding 9 gives 45, which also is divisible by 3.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The second part simply didn't strike me.